# NativeScript - Angular 2 Custom AppDelegate

Tags: ios, angular, mobile, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Is there an Angular 2 way to accomplish a custom AppDelegate like [this](https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-ios-background-execution/blob/master/app/custom-app-delegate.ts) in NativeScript? I've seen examples of how to do this without Angular, I'm just not sure where to register the AppDelegate in Angular 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can just add this to your **main.ts**:

```
import application = require("application");
import { CustomAppDelegate } from "./custom-app-delegate";
if (application.ios {
   application.ios.delegate = CustomAppDelegate;
}
platformNativeScriptDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: you're welcome. You'll find an sample here: 
https://github.com/hypery2k/nativescript-fabric/blob/develop/fabric.ios.appdelegate.ts

Comment: On `Nativescript-vue` I'm getting `TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property`